# How are font variations written

Tags: python, svg, fonts

I have been thinking for some time that variable fonts were simply combinations of multiple fonts, and that values were interpolated between them. However, I just read about this project, [protottypo](https://github.com/byte-foundry/prototypo) (which is unfortunately discontinued), and discovered about how they were storing their fonts as variables. See this screenshot from a promotional video, a few years ago:

[image: code making a glyph]

And it seemed just so logical! Why not use a real language-like format, with variables and all. In the picture above, it (kinda) looks like python code.

And then I thought "It must have been thought through, let's look at how OpenType font variations are implemented."

And I looked on the web for the schema and the specification, but could not find it.

So the actual question(s):

1. How are variable fonts stored in otf files? Is it simply, as I thought before, multiple fonts and the other values are interpolated between them? Is there a variable language like the one above used to write the variable parts of the font (obviously)?
2. Where can I find the TTF specification for variable fonts? Is there any?
3. Is there a way to write a variable font with a regular text file (of course involving some vector graphics of some sort, like: `const d = 'M23.6,0c-3.4,0-6.3,2.7-7.6,5.6C14.7,2.7,11.8,0,8.4,0C3.8,0,0,3.8,0,8.4c0,9.4,9.5,11.9,16,21.2 c6.1-9.3,16-12.1,16-21.2C32,3.8,28.2,0,23.6,0z'` (this one makes a heart)

Thank you (that's what the heart is for :)

Comment: "Variable fonts" are an OpenType extension. I don't think TrueType actually supported this at all, but Type 1 Postscript supported something similar called Multiple Master fonts. Perhaps you could start by following the links from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_master_fonts).

Comment: You are right, TrueType does not support font variations. I meant OpenType.
I have found sound resources. From [Microsoft's official OpenType font variations page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/otvaroverview), it looks like variations are still made by interpolating values between different variations of the same glyphs. [Here's another resource](https://github.com/jpamental/variable-fonts). However, I have not yet found an example of how to manage multiple axes. So no aswer yet.